# updating d3 chart with new data, the old data points not removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to update my d3 bubble chart with new data getting from the backend. However, it seems that the new data gets added to the chart but the old data points are not removed? What is the issue here?
Here is my function:

```
function updateGeoData(ds, de) {
        console.log("hit 233")
        const size = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([1, 100])  // What's in the data
            .range([4, 50])  // Size in pixel
        let updateData = $.get("/update_geo_data", {"ds":ds, "de":de});
        updateData.done(function (result) {
            var circles = svg.selectAll("myCircles").data(result, function(d) { return d; });
            circles.attr("class", "update");
            circles.enter().append("circle")
                .merge(circles)
                    .attr("cx", d => projection([d.long, d.lat])[0])
                    .attr("cy", d => projection([d.long, d.lat])[1])
                    .attr("r", d => size(d.count))
                    .style("fill", "69b3a2")
                    .attr("stroke", "#c99614")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .attr("fill-opacity", .4);
            circles.exit().remove();
        });
}
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That way, we can more easily answer your question and you'll be more likely to get a good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part right here is your problem:

```
svg.selectAll("myCircles")
```

`myCircles` isn't anything so the selection will always be empty, and you will always only append to it.

`svg.selectAll("circle")` should work as a selection for you. This will select all the circles currently plotted on and enter, update, remove appropriately.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot.